# Embedding JavaScript code in JSP won't call the JS function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Given the following code :

```
<%@ page language="java" 
    contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
    pageEncoding="windows-1256"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head><title>Bank application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Web Bank application</th></tr>
</table>
<br/>


<script>

function verifyEmptyString()
{
  var username = document.forms["loginForm"]["username"].value;
  var password = document.forms["loginForm"]["password"].value;

  return !(username == null || username == "" || password == null || password == "");
}     
</script>


<fieldset>
  <legend>Login Page - please enter your Username and Password</legend>

  <form id="loginForm" action="loginPage" onsubmit="verifyEmptyString()" > 

    <p style="font-size:15px">  <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">*</span> Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br> </p>
    <p style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">*</span>  Password : <input type="password" name="password"><br> </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

</body></html>
```

I'm trying to call the JS function `verifyEmptyString()` , but the JSP doesn't call the function.

Any idea what's wrong with the code ?

Comment: Javasript is a client side component. JSP is a server side component. The JSP obviously won't invoke it. You'll need to submit the form for it to get invoked. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: No . I don't want to submit the before making sure that the user didn't leave any blank fields ... in other words I want to make the user to enter something ,anything , but not an empty string .

Comment: That's what `onsubmit` is. You clickyour submit button. This generates an event which calls the `verifyEmptyString()`. If it returns `true`, the form submission happens. If the method returns `false`, submission doesn't happen.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: But it doesn't work ! The form is being forwarded anyway ,even when I submit a blank string ,it forwards me to another JSP .

Comment: What append if you add an alert() in the `verifyEmptyString()` function

Comment: @Lorenzo: Nothing , I tried it already . I think the function-call doesn't happen at all.

Comment: It is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/RBYnc/

Comment: @Lorenzo: Found the problem , details are in the answer below . Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is being called (I added an alert to verify).  But you want to return the value of the function in the onclick event:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="loginPage" onsubmit="return verifyEmptyString(this)" >
```

Comment: @ron Try it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_onsubmit). Check the value of the expression before you return it.

Comment: @Matt Jennings: Now it's working ... notice the `this` I changed in your post .

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/RBYnc/1/

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');

myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
    var username = document.forms["loginForm"]["username"].value;
    var password = document.forms["loginForm"]["password"].value;

    if(!(username == null || username == "" || password == null || password == "")){
        this.submit(); // If all the validations succeeded
        alert("submiting")
    }         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
<form onsubmit="return verifyEmptyString(this)" id="loginForm" action="loginPage"  >
```

For anyone who might encounter this problem in the future , you need to change the `onsubmit` ...

From this :

```
onsubmit="verifyEmptyString()"
```

To this :

```
onsubmit="return verifyEmptyString(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand why we need to pass `this`as a parameter to the function, because it is not accepted in the actual function definition `function verifyEmptyString()` . You are directly referring the form elements inside the function.

On the otherhand, if your code is similar to the below scenario,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function validateForm(obj) {
        var x = obj["firstname"].value;
        alert(x);
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="myForm" action="action.jsp"
        onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" method="post">
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"> <input
            type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

In this scenario, we are making use of the passed parameter `this`.
It refers to the current context, In our case, it is the `form` whose name is `myForm`

But in your original scenario, you are directly referring the form inside the javascript function by calling `document.forms["loginForm"]["username"].value`.